# Stopping all javascript execution

Tags: javascript, debugging, execution

Is there an equivalent to the php die() function for javascript that stops all javascript (including future callbacks for ajax requests, timeouts etc...) from running?

(NOTE: I can't use breakpoints in the debugger as the bug is in ie8 and the debugger prevents you from scrolling up/down the page while at a breakpoint; to be able to see at which point the bug is occurring I need to be able to scroll the page while the code is stopped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent to the php die() function for javascript that stops all javascript (including future callbacks for ajax requests, timeouts etc...) from running?

No.

That's all there is to say, really.

Comment: In that case, I'm going to rephrase my question as "What's the most efficient way to stop ie's javascript quirks driving you mad?"

Comment: @wheresrhys: Maybe use IE9 in IE8 compatibility mode? When it's just about the debugger…

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it can be done. This will end execution of the javascript.

`throw new Error('');`

Comment: don't think it'll prevent future callbacks being fired though

Comment: It won't. Timers will keep running, callbacks will keep firing.
 setTimeout(function(){alert("still runnin'")}, 2000);throw new Error('');

Answer (score 1):

```
debugger;
```

in console to pause execution (at least in chrome)