# If Statement Is True, Don't Run Rest Of Page

Tags: javascript

At the start of my page, I have this script that checks what time it is, and if it's past 2am or and before 6pm, it routes the user to a new page.

The routing works, but the rest of the code on my page still runs, which is a problem.

Is there any way to have only the first script run and ignore the rest if the time is within the specified range?

Here is the script:

```
<script>
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if(hour >= 2 || hour <= 18) {
window.location = "time-out";
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping all javascript execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728266/stopping-all-javascript-execution)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `hour >= 2 && hour <= 18`? Right now, your condition *always* evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @BenLee no that is not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have all the rest of the code inside an `else` block after your time check.

```
<script>
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if(hour >= 2 || hour <= 18) {
window.location = "time-out";
}
else{
    //code to be executed otherwise...
}
</script>
```

Or just call a function there that points to the code you actually want run.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make the code return, so no more javascript code is executed.

```
var validation = true

if(validation) {
   return 'We are done for today'
}

console.log('this wont fire');
```

2) Make the code throw an error, so no more javascript code is executed.

```
var validation = true;
if(validation) {
    throw new Error('We are done for today');
}
console.log('this wont fire')
```

If want to stop a separated script you can create a variable in the main scope that use one of this approach and then no more javascript should be executed.

e.g

```
var canExecute = true;
(function(){
    if(1 === 1) {
       canExecute = false;
    }

})();

(function(){
    if(canExecute === false) {
        return;
    }

    //other code goes here.

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide your page use this as the first code in the head

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if(hour >= 2 || hour <= 18) {
  document.write("<style>body { display:none }</style>"); 
  window.location.replace("time-out.html");
}
```

To not execute other code add the other code in an else:

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if(hour >= 2 || hour <= 18) {
  window.location.replace("time-out.html");
}
else {
  // other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if(hour >= 2 || hour <= 18) {
  window.location = "time-out";
}
else(){
  foo(); 
}
</script>
```

Does that fulfill what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place first all the dependent libraries like if you have using jQuery protocol, then you write the script after the including libs your code is perfect and will work fine and you don't have to put any conditional statements because javascript is a scripting language it reads the code line by line when your hours condition matched it will not load the rest of the script and redirect to the desire page but please make sure you have not using any document.ready like stuff.

```
<script>
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if(hour >= 2 || hour <= 18) {
window.location = "time-out";
}
</script>
```

Thanks.
Have a nice day